# In general, if $XY$ is independent of $Z$, does it necessarily imply that $Y$ is independent of $Z$?

Tags: probability

If I have that $XY$ (the product) is independent of $Z$, can I say that $Y$ is independent of $Z$? I tried coming up with a counter example but haven't been able to find one yet.

Answer (score 4):

Of course not. If, for example, $Y=Z, X=\frac{1}{Z} \ldots $

Comment: X=0 works pretty nicely as well.